# Why HAProxy docker container always exits?

Tags: docker, haproxy

I have a docker-compose, which spins up a HAProxy container. It uses `wait-for.sh` to wait for rails server to be alive. Once the connection is open, HAProxy exits.

HAProxy start command is something like this in the compose file: `command: ["./wait-for.sh", "rails-app:10520", "-t", "600", "--", "haproxy", "-f", "/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg"]`

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

HAProxy has startup parameter `-db`, which means "disable background mode". So the solution looks like `command: ["./wait-for.sh", "rails-app:10520", "-t", "600", "--", "haproxy", "-f", "/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg", "-db"]`